# my server-side shows nullPointerException when client-side runs java

Tags: java, bash, nullpointerexception, environment-variables, linux-mint

I have a server with Linux Mint OS which has a server-side Maven project that reads some environmental variables.

The environmental variables are declared in /etc/profile.d/my_env_vars.sh with:

```
export MY_VAR=/opt/my_app 
export PATH=$MY_VAR:$PATH
```

My server side has a function that when I run it from eclipse (installed in my server) it works fine with no errors.

```
public File convert( byte [] image) throws IOException {
    String filePath = System.getenv("MY_VAR");
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile("TEMP", "tmp", new File(filePath)); 
...
    return imagenFile;
}
```

My client-side also is a maven project. It sends a byte[] image to the function above and the server gives it back a result, but I got the NullPointerException error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
the second line of my function File imageFile = File.createTempFile("TEMP","temp...
```

Immediately in my server terminal I verified the environmental variable by echo $MY_VAR and it gives me the correct value (/opt/my_app)

Why does my function work correctly in my server-side but it gives nullPointerException error in the client-side?

I have tried by declaring the environmental variables in other files as ~/.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/bash.bashrc and nothing works. I read in other post to try to edit ~/.bash_profile but Linux Mint doesn't have that file.

I really appreciate any advice.

Comment: How did you run your server application? java -jar server-app.jar in command line???
First you must determite how your server app run and then double check your .profile. 
2nd, add more log into your application to trace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I run my server-side with Wildfly8. I start it in the terminal by: sudo ./standalone -b 0.0.0.0. Once its up, I can check the app in the browser, and in the terminal I can check any request from the browser or the cliente-side. My client-side it´s working in a raspberry pi. But it does not have any OS login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client, the `NullPointerException` is thrown because the environment variable is not set correctly and `null` is passed to the constructor of `File`.

Put `MY_VAR` in `~/.profile` and notice the file is only loaded once when you login. Therefore, after setting a new environment variable, make sure to log out and back in. If the file doesn't exist, create it.

You can test that it's set using:

```
$ env | grep MY_VAR
MY_VAR=value
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I realized I setup my env variables in my user, but I was running my server-side as root. Therefore, the env variables did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the commands, which create env variables and run the java application into the same sh script or the same "sandbox". I.e. you can put java command into /etc/profile.d/my_env_vars.sh or create another sh script and put into it the call of /etc/profile.d/my_env_vars.sh and after that run java application.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Actually, I hava a java.sh in the same path /etc/profile.d/ where I declared $JAVA_HOME. So, I put my env variables inside java.sh before $JAVA_HOME. But I receive the same null error. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting a `println` of the variable `filepath` in your client-side. 
If it is not printing the path, first of all check if client and server are able to connect to each other or not by using `ssh`.

I think the problem is because there is no connectivity between the client and server.